# login form with jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a form that user do login new page or allert ok $ nok

```
<form role="form" id="loginforms">
<input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" id="username">
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
<input type="password" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" id="password">
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
<input type="submit" value="ورود" class="btn btn-success" id="login">
</form>
```

and my controller to get data :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetUserNames(string uname, string pass)
    {
        bool status;
        var persons = this.prf_personRepository.Query.Where(c => c.UserName == uname && c.Password == pass)
            .Select(c => new { c.UserName,c.Password}).ToList();
        if (persons != null)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and jquery code :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#login").click(function () {
          $("#message").html("Logging in...");
          var data = { "uname": $("#username").val(), 
          "pass": $("#password").val()
           };
           var islogin = null;
           $.ajax({
           url: "/register/GetUserNames",
           type: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json",
           success: alert("ok"),
           Error: alert("not")
        });
       });
     });
</script>
```

when run project controller set status = true but in script success is null

Comment: What do you mean by "controller set success = true"?

Comment: my mean is status = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below lines

```
       success: alert("ok"),
       Error: alert("not")
```

to

```
       success: function(result){alert(result);},
       error: function(){alert("Error!")}
```

I would recommend to go through jQuery Docs for ajax
http://api.jquery.com/?s=ajax
http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: What's the right result type for the GetUserNames function for jQuery to work right?